# Why does this ifelse return an "object not found" error?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

I am attempting to build a `ggplot` but am running into an error here:

```
ggplot(nelMonthly) +
  geom_col(aes(month,
               overUnder,
           fill = ifelse(overUnder > 0, "red", "grey")),
           colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(month, overUnder, label = overUnder),
                  vjust = ifelse(overUnder > 0, -0.25, 1), # THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
                  size = 3,
                  colour = "black")
```

This returns:

```
Error in ifelse(overUnder > 0, -0.25, 1) : object 'overUnder' not found
```

However, if I explicitly specify the dataframe in the `ifelse` condition, it works correctly:

```
ggplot(nelMonthly) +
  geom_col(aes(month,
               overUnder,
           fill = ifelse(overUnder > 0, "red", "grey")),
           colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(month, overUnder, label = overUnder),
                  vjust = ifelse(nelMonthly$overUnder > 0, -0.25, 1),
                  size = 3,
                  colour = "black")
```

The problem I have with this is that it simply isn't how one should program because the data frame is passed inside `ggplot(df)`.

Am I missing something here?

Why is this happening and how can I rectify it?

Comment: I think that you can use column names like variable names because ggplot does the necessary handling behind the scenes. `ifelse()` does not do that handling so it outputs an error

Comment: But shouldn't it "inherit" the data frame from the `ggplot(df)` object?  Or are you saying that because `ifelse()` exists outside of `ggplot2` then it behaves according to its own defined methods?  If that is the case, then why does the first `ifelse` (`fill = ifelse(...)`) work and the second one not work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Also, you specified the wrong line that throws the error in your first code comment

Comment: Ah yes, I did (now rectified). So in that case why does the first `ifelse()` work and not the second one?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that one now that you mention it. Does it actually work as intended or does it go to default values ?

Comment: The first `ifelse()` works perfectly fine / as expected.  It's the second `ifelse()` that fails, which is why I am posing this question - why one and not the other?  The scenarios in which they are used (within `geom_X` objects) is identical in both cases, hence why I am confused here.  It could well be that this might be a bug, unless of course somebody can explain why this might be happening.

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: Maybe because 2nd one is outside aes? fill is inside aes but vjust is outside aes.

Comment: @zx8754 Surprisingly, that did it!  I thought I'd tried that but clearly must have overlooked it.  Add your comment as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `geom_col` we have the `fill` parameter inside `aes` whereas in `geom_text` we have the `vjust` parameter outside `aes`.

The documentation for `?aes` explains why:

> aes() is a quoting function. This means that its inputs are quoted to be evaluated in the context of the data. This makes it easy to work with variables from the data frame because you can name those directly

So within `aes`, R knows to look for `overUnder` in the object passed to the `data=` argument. Outside `aes`, however, R uses its normal behavior and looks for the `overUnder` object in the global environment.